# PHP search, show only session ID logs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to filter a session table, normally this is how I show the table list.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","esc");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sponsor ;");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>PIN</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Author ID</th>
<th>Entry Date</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['sid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['spin'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['spuname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['suid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['sdate'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I was wondering if it's possible on this part...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sponsor ;");
```

to add `Where spuname = 'spuname'`

I guess the way I'm doing it is wrong.

What I wanted to do is to show filtered tables, so the one that has the session will see only his logs.

Comment: Sure it is possible, where is spuname stored? So you can pass it to the query

Comment: `spuname` is stored @ sponsor table, its the table where members input data. @Chitowns24

Comment: `SELECT * FROM sponsor Where spuname = 'spuname'` ... exactly as you put it.

Comment: Okay so would you be using that users session data to fill in the WHERE `spuname` = "user data" because you can do a nice easy where statement but you need to figure out where the spuname you are looking for is coming from if that makes sense?

Comment: most likely its on a different table, it just copied its data during data input to `sponsor` table so I guess its on the `members` table wherein `spuname = username` if it is on members table @Chitowns24

Comment: Okay so we need to figure out how to get the username so we can use the username to search for the spuname

Comment: exactly, that's my problem :) @Chitowns24

Comment: Okay well you said the username is stored in a $_SESSION variable? Can you show us where the $_SESSION variable is defined?

Comment: I got this on the upper part of page `<?php
   session_start();
   if(!isset($_SESSION['members']))
   {
       header('location:matrix.php');
   }
  include('include/db.php');
  $sql ="SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ". $_SESSION['id'];
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
   ?>
`

Comment: "SELECT * FROM sponsor WHERE `spunaame` = '" . $row['username'] . "'"

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result`  error on this line  `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use where clause in your query. it would be

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sponsor Where spuname = 'spuname'");
```

Comment: did that but it doesn't show any. `sponsor` table wherein `spuname` is  just like a timestamp it automatically filled out once the `session id` from members table got its session. @Manoj Saini

Answer (score 0):

```
 mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM sponsor Where spuname = 'spuname'",$con);
```

try putting $con after your query